# About my versions of gnuplot and my terminals

Tags: ubuntu, plot, gnuplot, gif

I want to make a gif file doing an iteration of my files whose names are 1.dat,2.dat... I've tried  with this code:

```
!/usr/bin/gnuplot

unset key 

plot "dades.dat" using 1:2                      #

h=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN #1.69794089321728966E-045    #

plot "dades.dat" using 1:3                      #------>Dummy plots per tal de guardar en 
variables

d=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN #7.12168589558569665E-046    #          els valors ses amplades de ses malles

plot "dades.dat" using 1:4                      #

c=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN                              #

plot "dades.dat" using 1:5                      #

lam=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN                            #

plot "dades.dat" using 1:6                      #

n=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN                              #


i=0
set terminal gif      
unset key                        
set output "film.gif"
set title "V(x)"
set xlabel "x(m)"
set ylabel "V(V)"

i=i+1

if( i < n ) reread;
```

but when I execute with terminal my variable don't change and not stop the loop.

Later I use other forms to do the loop like:

```
do for [i=0:n] {
infile(i) = sprintf("%d.dat",i)
print i
plot infile(i) w l  using 1:2
}
```

But, when I execute, the terminal shows me the next missage:

```
do for [i=0:n] {
               ^
"./film.gnuplot", line 22: invalid complex constant
```

Very extrange because I have installed the 4.6 version of gnuplot. Then I tried to put in the terminal gnuplot ./film.gnuplot and then shows me:

```
set terminal gif      
             ^
"film.gnuplot", line 15: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list
```

And finally, I execute gnuplot, I write the help terminal comand and shows me that I have all this terminals installed:

```
   canvas            cgm               context           corel
    dumb              dxf               eepic             emf
    emtex             epslatex          fig               gpic
    hp2623a           hp2648            hpgl              imagen
    latex             mf                mif               mp
    pcl5              pop               postscript        pslatex
    pstex             pstricks          push              qms
    regis             svg               tek40xx           tek410x
    texdraw           tgif              tkcanvas          tpic
    vttek             xterm
```

Is very extrange because I always use the png terminal and never shows me the error, but when I execute with gnuplot, then it shows me the error.

I'm using Ubuntu

Comment: if you run `gnuplot --version` what is the output?  It is strange if, as you say, you normally use the png terminal but it is not listed as installed.  You can also run `print GPVAL_TERMINALS` within gnuplot to check which terminals are installed.

Comment: Thanks to answer. If I run gnuplot --version, it shows me that I have gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 5

Comment: Strange.  Which OS are you using?  Did you compile/install gnuplot yourself or use a package?  One thing I see is that you use `i` as a loop counter and variable, and gnuplot complains about an `invalid complex constant`, probably because it is trying to use `i` to mean the square root of -1.  Try using a different variable name (e.g. `ii`). The problem of `i` meaning the complex constant is common to a bunch of languages, so it is a good habit not to use `i` and `j` as variables.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, and I install gnuplot manually (downloading directly fron the gnuplot website, and instaling since the terminal).

About the name of the variable, I changed it but the error message still shows me.

Comment: Ok, I saw my installed terminals when I ran print GPVAL_TERMINALS. When I ran it in gnuplot I haven't got gif,png and jpeg, but when I ran my script without gnuplot (in the terminal I put ./film.gnuplot) then I have these terminals. Later, I execute the script whith gnuplot writing in the terminal (gnuplot ./film.gnuplot), I haven't got these terminals.... Very extrange.

Comment: @andyras Gnuplot uses the notation `{0,1}` for the imaginary constant `i`. Since version 4.4 doesn't know the `do for` loop, it expects a complex number after the opening bracket.

Comment: You still have two different gnuplot versions installed: `/usr/bin/gnuplot` (which is used when you run `./film.gnuplot`), and the `gnuplot` version, which you get when running `gnuplot` in the terminal. Run `which gnuplot` to see, which executable is used in the latter case.

Comment: Thanks to answer.When I run it, it shows me /usr/local/bin/gnuplot. Now, my question is how can install the 4.6 version of gnuplot, or how can I install the terminals in the terminal version (I've tried to install it before, but didn't function).

Comment: When you install gnuplot manually you might not be compiling with support for all the terminals you want.  You can add support by adding flags to `configure` (run `./configure --help` for a list), and you may have to install some Ubuntu packages to provide missing libraries.  If you run `./configure --prefix=~/bin/gnuplot-4.6` and then put `PATH=~/bin/gnuplot-4.6/bin:${PATH}` in your `.bashrc`, the new version of gnuplot should be the default one run at the command line.

Comment: Solutionated! I run this in the terminal:
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-dev libpango1.0-dev libreadline5-dev libx11-dev libxt-dev texinfo libgd2-xpm-dev

And then I reinstalled gnuplot. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Bones Oscar,

For me what works is the following. It is not very elegant.. I have a first script 'animar.gnu' in which I load the gif terminal and then a second script to plot the loop 'plot.gnu'. In the first one:

```
    set terminal gif animate
    set output 'peli.gif'
    ii=1
    load 'plot.gnu'
    set terminal wxt
    set output
```

The second one is the following

```
    infile(ii) = sprintf("%d.dat",ii)
    plot infile(ii) u 1:2
    ii = 1 + ii
    if (ii<4) reread
```

This will run from ii=1 to ii=4 and it plots the fist column vs the second one.

If the problem is that you don't have the gif terminal... Well this is a previous problem.

I once found the solution in a page similar to this one: http://www.gnuplot.info/announce_4.6.3.txt

Comment: Thanks to answer. I've tried to do it like your exemple but don't reconize me the terminal. I've tried to install it but I installed to the previuos version of gnuplot. Thank you.